# How can I add raw mp3 files in shufflefacts?

Tags: android, random, mp3

I made a random page with text and image now, I want to add mp3 files to it. When I click my fab button, there appears text and image, but when I add mp3 files like my codes, it gives an error and my application stop.

Is there any way to add raw files in shufflefacts?

Here is my facts.java code:

```
public class Facts {
    private int ivImage;
    private String mFact;
    private int videoView;
    public Facts(int ivImage, int videoView, String mFact) {
        this.ivImage = ivImage;
        this.videoView = videoView;
        this.mFact = mFact;
    }
    public int getivImage() {
        return ivImage;
    }
    public int getvideoView() {
      return videoView;
    }
    public String getmFact() {
        return mFact;
    }
    public String videoView() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and here is my random.class:

```
Toolbar mToolbar;
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
ImageView mFlower;
TextView mDescription;
VideoView videoView;
private FloatingActionButton fab;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar= getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    mToolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.cv));
    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    mFlower = findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
    mDescription = findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.vbn);
    showRandomFact();
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showRandomFact();

        }
    });
}

private void showRandomFact() {
    shuffleFacts();
    mFlower.setImageResource(factArray[0].getivImage());
    videoView.setVideoPath(factArray[0].videoView());
    mDescription.setText(factArray[0].getmFact());
}
Facts f01 = new Facts(R.drawable.a, R.raw.b,"hjgbfvjhsdbfvskhbsdıkfvsdkb");
Facts f02 = new Facts(R.drawable.aa, R.raw.b,"hjgbfvjhsdbfvskhbsdıkfvsdkb");
Facts f03 = new Facts(R.drawable.aas, R.raw.b,"hjgbfvjhsdbfvskhbsdıkfvsdkb");
Facts[] factArray = new Facts[] {
        f01,f02,f03
};
public boolean shuffleFacts(){
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(factArray));
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: I couldnt enter my random activity. when I click to enter my activity it says: unfortunately your apps stopped. so my fab button in my random activity

Comment: yes share your logcat of error.

Comment: 01-19 09:41:29.116 4161-4179/com.xxxx.flowers W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...   01-19 09:41:29.001 4161-4161/com.xxx.flowers W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable

Comment: and this 01-19 09:41:28.691 4161-4161/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10076: Read-only file system

Comment: does your project have  raw folder? and exist R.raw.b file ?

Comment: and what is `b` ? audio file ?

Comment: yes I have raw file. e.mp3 and b.mp3 my audio file